# Can't connect: POP3 connection broken in response

Tags: php, gmail, imap, email-attachments, pop3

I am trying to download the attachments from a gmail account but am failing so far.

I have tried some IMAP snippet but had this error:

```
Cannot connect to Gmail: Can't open mailbox {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX: invalid remote specification
```

So decided to give POP a try but gave this error:

```
Can't connect: POP3 connection broken in response
```

The code i found for POP was:

```
if( $mbox = imap_open("{pop.gmail.com:995/pop3}INBOX", "me@gmail", "mypassword")){
$path = "saved_email_docs";
$check = imap_mailboxmsginfo($mbox);     
function getmsg($mbox,$mid) {   
    global $charset,$htmlmsg,$plainmsg,$attachments,$from,$to,$subj,$timages,$path;
    $htmlmsg = $plainmsg = $charset = '';
    $attachments = array();
    // HEADER
    $h = imap_headerinfo($mbox,$mid);
    // add code here to get date, from, to, cc, subject...
    $date = $h->date;
    $from = $h->fromaddress;
    $to = $h->toaddress;
      $subj = htmlspecialchars($h->Subject);
    // BODY
    $s = imap_fetchstructure($mbox,$mid);
    if (!$s->parts)  // simple
    getpart($mbox,$mid,$s,0);  // pass 0 as part-number
    else {  // multipart: cycle through each part
    foreach ($s->parts as $partno0=>$p)
      getpart($mbox,$mid,$p,$partno0+1);
    }
}

function getpart($mbox,$mid,$p,$partno) {
    // $partno = '1', '2', '2.1', '2.1.3', etc for multipart, 0 if simple
    global $htmlmsg,$plainmsg,$charset,$attachments,$partid,$last_mail_id,$patterns,$pic,$newstr,$c,$ok,$timages,$subj,$path;
    $patterns = array();
    $pic =  array();
    $image=array();
    $data = ($partno) ? imap_fetchbody($mbox,$mid,$partno) : imap_body($mbox,$mid);  // simple
    if ($p->encoding==4)
    $data = quoted_printable_decode($data);
    else if ($p->encoding==3)
    $data = base64_decode($data);
    // PARAMETERS    // get all parameters, like charset, filenames of attachments, etc.
    $params = array();
    if ($p->parameters)
    foreach ($p->parameters as $x)
        $params[strtolower($x->attribute)] = $x->value;
    if ($p->dparameters)
    foreach ($p->dparameters as $x)
        $params[strtolower($x->attribute)] = $x->value;

    // ATTACHMENT    // Any part with a filename is an attachment,
    // so an attached text file (type 0) is not mistaken as the message.
    if ($params['filename'] || $params['name']) {
    $partid = htmlentities($p->id,ENT_QUOTES);

       // filename may be given as 'Filename' or 'Name' or both
    $filename = ($params['filename'])? $params['filename'] : $params['name'];
    // filename may be encoded, so see imap_mime_header_decode()
     $attachments[$filename] = $data;  // this is a problem if two files have same name
    //store id and filename in array
    $image[$key] = $filename;

    }
    //save the attachments in the directory
    foreach( $attachments as $key => $val){
      $fname = $key;
      $fp = fopen("$path/$fname","w");
      fwrite($fp, $val);
      fclose($fp);
    }
        // TEXT
        if ($p->type==0 && $data) {
        // Messages may be split in different parts because of inline attachments,   // so append parts together with blank row.
        if (strtolower($p->subtype)=='plain')
            $plainmsg .= trim($data)."\n\n";
        else
            //preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$data, $result);
            $htmlmsg .= $data."<br><br>";
            $charset = $params['charset'];  // assume all parts are same charset
        }

    // There are no PHP functions to parse embedded messages, so this just appends the raw source to the main message.
    else if ($p->type==2 && $data) {
    $plainmsg .= $data."\n\n";
    }
    // SUBPART RECURSION
    if ($p->parts) {
    foreach ($p->parts as $partno0=>$p2)
        getpart($mbox,$mid,$p2,$partno.'.'.($partno0+1));  // 1.2, 1.2.1, etc.
    }
}

$attachments = array();
$num_msg = imap_num_msg($mbox);
if($num_msg>0) {
    getmsg($mbox,1);
}else {
     echo "Sorry!...No Messages in MailBox...<br>";
}

//imap_delete and imap_expunge are used to delete the mail after fetching....Uncomment it if you want to delete the mail from mailbox
//imap_delete($mbox,1); 
//imap_expunge($mbox);
imap_close($mbox);

}
else { exit ("Can't connect: " . imap_last_error() ."\n");  echo "FAIL!\n"; 
}
```

Any ideas?